# Flutter/Dart unit testing, how to advance time for Timer

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, asynchronous, time

I have a `Stream<T>` in my flutter app which uses `timeout()` under hood. Everything works fine, but running unit tests takes a while, since they have to wait every time for the timeout.

As I can see from sources `timeout()` implementation is based on `Timer()`. Is there any way to artificially advance time for `Timer()` on unit test environment?

For example in RxJava there is `TestScheduler` which has methods like `advanceTimeBy/advanceTimeTo`. I am looking for similar functionality.

**Update:**

The code could look like this:

```
extension StreamEx<T> on Stream<T> {

  /// timeout only the first emission
  Stream<T> timeoutFirst(Duration timeLimit) =>
      MergeStream([
        take(1).timeout(timeLimit), 
        skip(1),
      ]);
}
```

My requirement for the test here is that its runtime should not depend on whatever passed as `timeLimit` to the method. It possible with RxJava but how to fix it at Darts streams.

**Update:**

The test could look like this:

```
void main() async {
  group(
    'StreamEx.timeoutFirst',
    () {
      const TIMEOUT = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
      const DELAY = Duration(milliseconds: 110);
      test(
        'should throw `TimeoutException` if it took too long for the first emission',
        () async {
          final subject = BehaviorSubject<int>();
          final stream = subject.timeoutFirst(TIMEOUT).dump('tag0');

          expectLater(
            stream,
            emitsInOrder([
              emitsError(isInstanceOf<TimeoutException>()),
              emits(equals(1)),
              emits(equals(2)),
            ]),
          );

          await Future.delayed(DELAY);
          subject.add(1);
          subject.add(2);
          subject.close();
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: can you show some code please

Comment: Well, the code would not be more complex than `getSomeStream().timeout(Duration(seconds: 25))` There is no way how to mock 25 seconds from outside. Of course the real code is more complex but the main idea should be clear I think. Please tell me if you still think that code in the question would help more.

Comment: I am trying to see if your methods can be mocked somehow to avoid the timer

Comment: Ok, I added some code.

Comment: I meant more code:) maybe a code for a test as well

Comment: Ok, I added some test code as well (-: